# How can I find the index of two integers that have the smallest difference from a series of integers?

Tags: c++

i've a problem that asks me to print the index of the integers whose difference is smallest. If the inputs are `5` and `10 12 13 15 10`, I have to print `5 1`. The problem is [here](https://codeforces.com/contest/34/problem/A). Below is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;
int main(){
    int n;
    int temp=1005,pos1=0,pos2=0;
    cin>>n;
    vector <int> vec;
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
        int in; cin>>in;
        vec.push_back(in);
    }
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
        for(int j=1;j<n;j++){
            if(i==j)break;
            int ans=abs(vec[i]-vec[j]);
            cout<<i+1<<"-"<<j+1<<" = "<<ans<<endl;
            if(ans<temp){
                temp=ans;
                pos1=i,pos2=j;
            }
        }
    }

    cout<<pos1+1<<" "<<pos2+1<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: what's the problem? ("it does not work" is not an answer))

Comment: it gives wrong output at times and doesnt get accepted. i dont understand where's the flaw here rn

Comment: I think that you might've missed the part where it tells you that the soldiers are standing in a circle. Also, `i` gets updated every iteration, so I don't think you want to start `j` from 1.

Comment: Just as a side note: [Why is “using namespace std;” considered bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice)

Comment: why not sort the vector and then do binary serche?

Comment: Your loop does not examine neighbouring elements. The first iteration compares the first element to all other elements. The second exits immediately. The third iteration compares the  second and third elements. The fourth compares the fourth element to the second and third. Work out an algorithm first. Draw numbers in a circle on paper and figure out what to do.

Answer (score 1):

Here's my solution in C. Remember that you need only be concerned with *neighboring* elements and that the soldiers are organized in a circle. Also, I found it a bit weird that the solution is asking for indexes starting at 1 and not 0.

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define ABS(n) ((n) * (((n) > 0) - ((n) < 0)))

void solution(int n, int soldiers[static 2])
{
    int indexA  = 1,
        indexB  = 2,
        minDiff = ABS(soldiers[0] - soldiers[1]),
        heightDiff;
    
    for (int i = 1; i < n; i++)
    {
        if ((heightDiff = ABS(soldiers[i] - soldiers[(i + 1) % n])) < minDiff)
        {
            minDiff = heightDiff;
            indexA = i + 1;
            indexB = ((i + 1) % n) + 1;
        }
    }
    
    printf("%d %d\n", indexA, indexB);
}

int main()
{
    solution(5, (int[5]){10, 12, 13, 15, 10});
    //5 1
    solution(4, (int[4]){10, 20, 30, 40});
    //1 2

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The soldiers stand in a circle and you are supposed to look at soldiers standing next to each other.

This means you don't need the j loop. You can simply compare `vec[i]` with `vec[(i+1) % n]`.